# AG listener with MultiSubnetfailover True on Named Instance

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have an AG configuration with databases on a Named instance. I have enabled

`multisubnetfailover =true` and `registerallprovidersip =1`

I just saw some blurb on the web that these settings are not supported by Named Instances.

Has anyone used these settings on a named instance and had a successful fast failover from 1 subnet to another?

Confusing details on [leveraging multi subnet failover](https://johnlouros.com/blog/leveraging-multi-subnet-failover) and [sql server always on listeners](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-always-on-listeners/).

Comment: There is nothing in the [official doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sqlclient-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery) that says Named Instances aren't supported by MultiSubnetFailover, and I've never encountered an issue using it with Named Instances. Have you actually encountered any issues in testing failover?

Answer (score 0):

As HandyD stated - the official doc does not mention issues with named instances. I also have not experienced any issues with AO multi-subnet failover with named instances.

The [SQL Shack article](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-always-on-listeners/) to which you linked states: "It does not support SQL named instances. **We can connect named SQL instances using a SQL listener**" (emphasis added).  I think the confusion is caused by poor choice of words.  I suspect what the author meant to say is that in order for multi-subnet failover to work, a listener *must* be used to connect, using the instance names to connect will not work.